Visual Studio 17, 19, 22, Windows 10 or 11 pro: Error Unable to remove directory "bin\Debug\app.publish\"
Windows 10 or 11 pro, Visual Studio 2022 and previous versions:(c#)
I have been using VS sporadically over the years, and now and then I get the error:
"Error Unable to remove directory "bin\Debug\app.publish". Access to the path 'bin\Debug\app.publish' is denied".
The program is ok, except that it can not be run.
After searching and reading many suggestions, most of which refer to older VS versions, the only remedy I found that worked for me for all projects was to move the whole VS program from drive C: to drive D: (or any other than C).
This is not the best solution, as it is out of the default setup, and very inconvenient.
Is there another proven solution to this problem on drive C:?
Thanks

Nobody here has any idea what steps need to be taken to get to whatever you're complaining above. I also don't see any question specifically about programming here. Please, in case you haven't, take the [tour] and read [ask].

I did see similar issues where output files couldn't be updated/deleted any more because they were locked by VS itself, but in the worst case, I had to restart VS to fix this.

Sometimes VS locked it files by accident,and Restart it will help.Also put your files in C: inproperly will causing permission issue as it is the system partition and you won't be able to gain write access without admin permissions.
